# Is a permutation of block diagonals similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $A=B_1\oplus\cdots \oplus B_n$.

Let $\sigma\in S_n$ be a permutation.

Then are $A$ and $B_{\sigma(1)}\oplus \cdots \oplus B_{\sigma(n)}$ similar?

I have proven that this is true, but I want to make sure. Is this statement really true?

(Proof: View $A$ as a linear transformation and then re-order the standard ordered basis corresponding to $\sigma$. Since $A$ is a block diagonal, the resultant and $A$ are similar)

Comment: Your proof and your result are both correct. Explicitly, the two are similar through the corresponding permutation matrix, which is seen as the change of basis matrix from your original basis to your permuted one.

Comment: @EuYu Thank you. Would you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof and your result are both correct. Explicitly, the two are similar through the corresponding permutation matrix, which is seen as the change of basis matrix from your original basis to your permuted one.